# Deploy new container on AKS using Jenkins with Azure Container Service

Tags: azure, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, azure-aks

I'm trying to create my first job in Jenkins and Azure Container Service but I ran with a little issue, there is a "config file" section and for my understanding, this is the field where I need to put my YMAL files with the wanted configuration that the Jenkins need to upload to the AKS.

I have tried to insert the full location of the YAML file but it keeps telling me that I need to use `"Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '/var/jenkins_home/aks-test-yml/create-namespace.yml"` and after that, I tried to use Ant GLOB syntax but it still filed cause `"No config files matches the path pattern: **\create-namespace.yml"`.

can someone give me an example of which config file should I provide and how to provide his location?

**Edit:**
the problem is that the plugins aren't supported. After they will release a new version of the Azure Container Service plugin hopefully those bugs will be solved after an update.

Comment: Can you try using the relative path to your yaml from the job's workspace? Ref: https://groups.google.com/g/job-dsl-plugin/c/1ybmBMm96-A/m/oSKMFF2FAgAJ

Comment: Hi,
I have just needed to add the YAML file to the path: `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/aks-test-job/` but now there is a new error message: `ERROR: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Namespace; exception=Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Namespace
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:  apiVersion: v1`

it has an error for my YAML config file that I have already tested in the Azure portal.

this simple YAML file looks like this:
`apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: test-namespace`

Comment: Check out [this link](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62954).

Comment: Hi,
the `Kubernetes Continuous Deploy` plugin must be at least in version 2.3.0 to work with the latest version of the `Azure Container Service` plugin. I have done some tests and the first working version of the `Azure Container Service` plugin is 1.0.0 and the minimum version for the `Kubernetes Continuous Deploy` plugin is 2.0.1' after I downloaded and installed those two versions the same error accord...